# How to use a PHP wildcard?

Tags: php, wildcard

I have a function that deletes a set of cookies on customer logout, my problem is that every time a cookie is deleted on logout - when the customer returns to the website and logs back in it is generated again, and when it's generated again a number is appended to the end.

Cookie Name's are generated as follows,

```
affiliate_account_code_1
affiliate_account_code_2
affiliate_account_code_3
```

and can go all the way up to the 100's.

My question is is there a way in PHP to say, if the string matches this criteria `affiliate_account_code_*` like using a wild card in the terminal? Is there a way to try and catch any number that is appended to the string.

After searching

> PHP wildcard

I found that there is a  `fnmatch()` function, having never used it I am unsure if it's suitable for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily possible with a regular expression and [`preg_match`](http://de3.php.net/preg_match):

```
preg_match('/affiliate_account_code_(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
```

`\d+` matches an infinite (at least one) number of digits. The match between the parentheses can be retrieved using `$matches[1]`.

Demo:

```
php> $string = 'affiliate_account_code_1';
'affiliate_account_code_1'
php> preg_match('/affiliate_account_code_(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
int(1)
php> $matches;
array (
  0 => 'affiliate_account_code_1',
  1 => '1',
)
```